# Unable to Style checkbox in IE

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a table column in which, a checkbox is followed by a label. A sample HTML code is :

```
< td class = "namecell" >< input type="checkbox"  class = "checkboxclass" value="cs1" /> < label class = "celllabel" id = "nlcs1" >lable data < /label> < /td>
```

However in IE the checkbox and the label are not aligned in the same line. The label goes into next line this is affected the look and the overall alignment of the page. However this isn't a problem with other browsers like Firefox and Chrome.
I tried specifying width and height but couldn't solve the problem. I basically want both the checkbox and the label to be on the same line.

Does anyone has previously faced such a problem. Help needed.

Comment: Do either of the elements have display: block on them? If so, remove it. Or if that's not possible, add a float to either element to force it to go to whatever side you want it on.

Comment: Also, a good idea is to remove all the unnecessary spacing you have. It could possibly be the answer you're looking for. i.e. '< td class = "namecell" >' should in fact be '<td class="namecell">'

Comment: @Patrik Although you're right in principle, your example is not the right one. All the spaces in `< td class = namecell" >` are allowed. However `< /td>` is in error.

Comment: the spaces provided in the code was to make the html code come in my post here. I didnt have any space in my actual code.

Comment: That didn't make any sense whatsoever. Why would you add spaces within your code, when it's your code that you need help with?..

Answer (score 0):

In general a non-breaking space suffices somewhat.

```
<td class="namecell"><label
  class="celllabel"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass"
  value="cs1" />&nbsp;lable data </label></td>
```

Comment: Adjusting the width solved the problem thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that work:

1. Use the attribute `nowrap="nowrap"` (or just `nowrap` when not using XHTML) in the `td` tag.
2. Wrap the contents of the `td` element inside `nobr` markup:
   `<td ...><nobr>...</nobr></td>`

Someone might complain that `nowrap` has been deprecated and that `nobr` is nonstandard, but they are tools that actually do the job. In this case they both seem to work, but in general, `nobr` works in some cases where `nowrap` doesn’t.

Using `&nbsp;` (or an actual no-break space) doesn’t help. In fact the checkbox and the label may get displayed on separate lines even when no space intervenes, unless you use the methods mentioned.

Using `white-space: nowrap` in CSS (on the `td` element) should help by the CSS 2.1 spec, but it does not work in practice.

The problem appears only when there is something that prevents browsers from expanding the cell width to accommodate its content on one line. This might be a width specification, for example. Note that forcing the checkbox and the label on the same line may cause the with specification to be overridden.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adjusting the width of the td solved the problem. However this problem didnt surface when dealing with firefox or chrome. It only  surfaced in IE.